# How do I build one dynamic JSON object using data from two different async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to build one JSON object with data that I scrape from a website in two different async functions, below is my current code:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");
var jsonObject = {};
async function scrapeSite(){

    const result = await axios.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/corporate-tax-rate");

    const $ = cheerio.load(result.data);
    
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_UpdatePanel1 > div > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)").each((index, element) => {
        console.log($(element).text());
        
    });

    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_UpdatePanel1 > div > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > a").each((index, element) => {

        console.log($(element).text().trim());
        

    });
    
    return "Done";

}
console.log(jsonObject);
async function scrapeSiteYield(){

    const yieldResult = await axios.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/forecast/government-bond-10y");

    const $ = cheerio.load(yieldResult.data);
    $("#p").each((index, element) => {
        console.log("Yield: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    

    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("Major: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("Europe: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(12) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("America: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(16) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("Asia: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(20) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("Australia: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    $("#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(24) > div > table > tbody > tr > td.datatable-item-first").each((index, element) => {

        console.log("Africa: "+$(element).text().trim());
    });
    
    
    return "Done";

}
scrapeSite();
scrapeSiteYield();
```

Below is the JSON Object I require:

```
{
    [
        {
            "Country":"South Africa",
            "Taxrate": 15,
            "Yield" : 0.55
        },
        {
            "Country":"Australia",
            "Taxrate": 20,
            "Yield" : 0.6506
        }
    ]
}
```

- Country is being returned in both async functions.
- Taxrate is being returned in the first async function.
- Yield is being returned in the second async function.

Comment: It would help if you provided a *minimal* example. Also,  remember HTML element IDs must be unique - you cannot have multiple elements named `p`

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a little and now it does what you need. You can [check in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Create-one-JSON-from-two-scrape-functions-Nodejs#index.js). The only point is that Yield is not available everywhere.

Code:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

async function scrapeSite() {
  const results = [];
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const result = await axios.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/corporate-tax-rate");

    const $ = cheerio.load(result.data);

    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_UpdatePanel1 tr").each((index, element) => {
      results[index] = {
        Taxrate: $(element).find("td:nth-child(3)").text(),
        Country: $(element).find("td:nth-child(1) > a").text().trim(),
      };
    });
    resolve(results);
  });
}

async function scrapeSiteYield(results) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const yieldResult = await axios.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/forecast/government-bond-10y");

    const $ = cheerio.load(yieldResult.data);
    $(".table tr").each((index, element) => {
      let country = $(element).find(".datatable-item-first a").text().trim();
      if (country.includes("UK")) country = "United Kingdom";
      if (country.includes("US")) country = "United States";
      if (country.includes("15Y")) country = "Peru";
      results.forEach((el) => {
        if (country.includes(el.Country)) {
          el.Yield = $(element).find("#p").text().trim();
        }
      });
    });

    resolve(results);
  });
}
scrapeSite().then(scrapeSiteYield).then(console.log);
```

Output:

```
[
  { "Taxrate": "20", "Country": "Afghanistan" },
  { "Taxrate": "15", "Country": "Albania" },
  { "Taxrate": "26", "Country": "Algeria" },
  { "Taxrate": "30", "Country": "Angola" },
  { "Taxrate": "30", "Country": "Argentina" },
  { "Taxrate": "18", "Country": "Armenia" },
  { "Taxrate": "25", "Country": "Aruba" },
  { "Taxrate": "30", "Country": "Australia", "Yield": "3.4910" },
  { "Taxrate": "25", "Country": "Austria", "Yield": "1.5030" },
  { "Taxrate": "20", "Country": "Azerbaijan" },
  { "Taxrate": "0", "Country": "Bahamas" },
  { "Taxrate": "0", "Country": "Bahrain" },
... other results
]
```